# Showing related items from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch a value from my first sql query "Engine.type" and put this in a variable so I can use in another query. However instead of echoing the rows of similar engine type its echoing the whole table. Anyone know the problem?

**Here is the first query:**

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT
  Owner.id,
  Engine.type,
  Engine.top_speed,
  Engine.acceleration,
  Car.number_plate,
  Car.image,
  Car.colour,
  Car.price
FROM
  Car
INNER JOIN
  Model ON Car.model_id = Model.id
INNER JOIN Engine ON
  Car.engine_id = Engine.id
INNER JOIN Owner ON 
    Car.Owner_id= Owner.id
WHERE
  Model.id = :id");
$stmt->bindValue(':id',$carId);
$stmt->execute();
$car=$stmt->fetchALL();
```

**Here is where I want the value you to go:**

```
$simlar = $car['type'];
$stmt1 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Car INNER JOIN Engine ON Car.engine_id 
= Engine.id WHERE Engine.type LIKE :enginetype LIMIT 3'); //search for car 
with simlar engine type 
$stmt1->bindValue(':enginetype','%'.$simlar.'%');


$stmt1->execute();
$simlaritem=$stmt1->fetchALL();
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling fetchAll() on your results for the first query, and storing it in `$car`. This means that `$car` is an array of arrays containing the results.

Are you looping through $car? My guess, from the code you've posted, is that if you did a `var_dump($car)`, you would see that actually have to have `$simlar = $car[0]['type'];`. Otherwise, `$simlar` would have a blank value (since there is no `$car['type']`), and thus your second query is just searching for `WHERE Engine.type LIKE '%%'`.

See the examples in the PHP documentation for PDO's [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) for more details.

---

For clarity, I believe you are expecting `$car` to return something like this:

```
Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [0] => 1
        [type] => SUV
        [1] => SUV
        ...
    )
```

But in reality, `$car` actually looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [type] => SUV
            [1] => SUV
            ...
        )
)
```